# A problem about effective uniformly distribution

Tags: number-theory, uniform-distribution, diophantine-approximation

The original problem is following:

> **Problem 1**
>   $\lim_{N\to \infty}|\frac{\#\{1\leq n\leq N |\ \ \ [n\sqrt2]=0(mod 2)\}}{N}|=\frac{N}{2}+O(ln(N))$.

This problem is not very difficult, in fact $\#{\{1\leq n\leq N |\ \ \ [n\sqrt2]=0(mod 2)\}}=\#\{1\leq n\leq N| \{n\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\}\in (0,\frac{1}{2})\} $.

and due to the observation $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ is smooth and following effective uniformly distribution result:

> **Theorem (effective uniformly distribution for smooth irrational number)**
>   $\alpha \in \mathbb R- \mathbb Q$ is a smooth irrational number, then we have, $\forall 0<a<b<1$,
>   $$\#\{1\leq n\leq N\ |\  \{\alpha n\}\in (a,b) \}=(b-a)N+O(log(N))$$

The proof of the theorem is a careful look at the continue fractional of $\alpha$. Now we shift to two natural emerge problems, but more difficult. I do not know how to handle them.

> **Problem 2** if $\alpha$ is an irrational number. $P(n)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficient, under what assume on $\alpha$ we have,
>   $$\#\{1\leq n\leq N\ |\  \{\alpha P(n)\}\in (a,b) \}=(b-a)N+O(log(N))$$
>   Is it enough if we assume $\alpha$ is smooth?

I do not know if the problem is a good question, may be we should change the error term $log(N)$ to something else.

A remark, if we just care about the uniformly distribution, this could be done by Weyl method or van der coput trick, the key point is what can we say about the error term as better as possible?

> **Problem 3**  if $\alpha$ is an irrational number. $Q(n)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficient, under what assume on $\alpha$ we have good asymptotic for,
>   $$\#\{1\leq n\leq N\ |\  \exists m\in \mathbb N^*,[\alpha n]=Q(m) \}?$$
>   Is it enough if we assume $\alpha$ is smooth to gain such a asymptotic?

Comment: An irrational number is said to be *smooth* if the terms of its continued fraction are bounded, correct? For instance $\sqrt{2}$ is smooth since $\sqrt{2}=[1;\overline{2}]$ and $\varphi$ is smooth since $\varphi=[1;\overline{1}]$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, yeah you are right, exactly.

Comment: The statement of problem $2$ should be simple to prove if $O(\log n)$ is replaced by $O\left[\left(\log n\right)^{\deg P}\right]$ or something like that, by just mimicking the proof of the first Theorem, i.e. by considering suitable exponential sums and applying Weyl's bound.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, good point! I have not realized this truth until you point out! thanks a lots!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Problem 3 seems more interesting, In my opinion this problem is similar to the problem: There are infinite many primes in irreducible polynomial, I am sorry, I forget the name of this conjecture, one special case of it is weather there is infinite primes in $n^2+1$... We just image the k-th best approximation of $\alpha$ by rational number $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ as k-th primes, "smooth" just mean the promotion of  k-th and (k+1)-th "primes" is uniformly bonded.

Comment: Landau's conjecture alone is a horribly difficult problem, but your Problem $3$ is much different in my opinion. $\lfloor \alpha n\rfloor$ form a [Beatty sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence) with a positive density, so it is very likely that the range of almost any polynomial with integer coefficients intersects such sequence infinite times.

Comment: Yes you are right, but what happen if we consider "problem 4", combine the difficulties in problem 2 and problem 3, i.e. get an reasonable estimate and reasonable error term for the set $\#\{1\leq n\leq N\ |\exists m\in N^*, [\alpha P(n)]= Q(m)\}$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I have two different strategy to deal with problem 3, both seems to make sense, Strategy 1:

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I have two different strategy to deal with problem 3, both seems to make sense, Strategy 1: for simplify we take $Q(n)$ to be a quadratic polynomial. Step 1, transforms the structure form linear to bilinear( for $deg(Q(n))\geq 3$, multilinear). we consider the partition $\mathbb N^*= \amalg_{k\geq 0} A_k$, $A_k=\{a_m| a_m=m^2+k, n\leq (m+1)^2\}$. then there is a shift $T:A_k\to A_{k+1}, x\to x+1, \forall k\geq 0$. and for every $k$, in $A_k$ there is a shift $Ta_m=a_{m+1}, a_{m+1}=a_m+2m+1$. Now we use the result of linear partition on short interval $[n^2_1,(n+1)^2-1]$.

Comment: Now we could equipped a natural measure on the space $\amalg_{0\leq k\leq 2n} A_k$, the measure is deformation from finite sum of dirac measure to the Lesbegue measure on $(0,1)$ along $n\to \infty$ (you can image it as the plank constant is smaller and smaller). Because we have very good error term for the uniformly distribution on $\amalg_{0\leq k\leq 2n}$, the error term is $O(log(N)^{deg(Q)})$,.

Comment: so we could get some estimate from the uniformly distribution on horizontal space to distribution on vertical space (question 3 is related to the uniformly distribution of $[n\alpha]$ in every this space). It seems we can proof the intersection of $[n\alpha]$ with every lesbegue measure positive subset is infinite and obey the uniformly distribution but the estimate is too rude to get the estimate in every independent vertical line...

Comment: I explain the second approach, on the other hand, when $Q(k)=k^2+1$ Problem 3 is morally equivalent to say there is infinity $n$ such that $\{\sqrt\{\alpha n\}\in (1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\}$ and even a uniformly distribution result: there is morally $\sqrt{n}$ numbers in $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $\{\alpha \sqrt{n}\}\in (0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$, this is not trivial but we still could say something about it. A key obersevation is that there is nearly 1 element in $n\in [m^2+1,m^2+2m]$ such that satisfied the condition.

Comment: in fact, when we shift from $\{\sqrt{n}\alpha\}$ to $\{\sqrt{n+1}\alpha\}$, the fractional changed nearly $\frac{1}{m}$ and the interval $[0,1]$ is nearly to be equivalent divide into $m$ parts in this case. This obersevation end the proof, for $deg(Q)\geq 3$, the approach still make sense I think. But It seems still very difficult for me to find some nontrivial result on problem 4.